# How to create a trendline with gaps of missing data in python?

Tags: python, trendline

So I'm new to python AND data analysis, but have been tasked to create a scatter plot.  The data set that I'm using has many elements containing None values.  When I use the polyfit method to create a trendline(best-fit line) I get errors for the Nones.  I've tried using lists and numpy arrays with dismal results.  I've also tried masked_array, masked_invalid, ect. in MULTIPLE configurations, but it kept giving me an array filled with Nones.  Is there a way of creating a trendline in such a way that I don't need to remove the elements that have None values?  I need them to keep my plot dimensions correct. I'm using Python 2.7.  This is what I got so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import numpy.ma as ma
import pylab
#The InterpolatedUnivariateSpline method popped up during my endeavor 
#to extrapolate the trendline through the gaps in data.
#To be honest, I don't think its doing anything for me...
from scipy.interpolate import InterpolatedUnivariateSpline  

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax.scatter(y, dbm, color = 'purple', marker = 'o', s = 100)
plt.xlim(min(y), max(y)) 
plt.xlabel('Temp - C')
dbm_array = np.asarray(dbm) #dbm and y are lists earlier in the program
y_array = np.asarray(y)

x = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), len(y))
order = 1
s = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(y, dbm, k=order)
blah = s(x)
plt.plot(y, blah, '--k')
```

This gives me the scatter plot without the trendline for some reason.  No errors, so I guess I got that going for me....
Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: 'blah' is an array just containing nans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, if you have arrays, there should be no `None`s in them, just `nan`s. This is because `None` is an object which cannot be expressed as a number. So, the first problem may be here. Let's have a look:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([None, 1, 2, 3, 4, None])
```

What do we get?

```
>>> a
array([None, 1, 2, 3, 4, None], dtype=object)
```

This is most certainly something we did not. It is an array of objects, which is most of the time something not very useful. You cannot perform any calculations on that one:

```
>>> 2*a
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'int' and 'NoneType'
```

This happens because the element-wise multiplication tries to multiply `2*None`.

So, what you really want to have is:

```
>>> a = np.array([np.nan, 1, 2, 3, 4, np.nan])
>>> a
array([ nan,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  nan])
>>> a.dtype
dtype('float64')
>>> 2 * a
array([ nan,   2.,   4.,   6.,   8.,  nan])
```

Now everything works as expected.

So, the first thing is to check that your input arrays have the correct form. If you then have problems with curve fitting, you may create an array without the nasty `nan`s in there:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[0,np.nan], [1, 1], [2, 1.5], [3.2, np.nan], [4, 5]])
b = a[-np.isnan(a[:,1])]
```

Let's see the contents of `a` and `b`:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0. ,  nan],
       [ 1. ,  1. ],
       [ 2. ,  1.5],
       [ 3.2,  nan],
       [ 4. ,  5. ]])
>>> b
array([[ 1. ,  1. ],
       [ 2. ,  1.5],
       [ 4. ,  5. ]])
```

And this is what you want. The curve is fitted with `b` without any `nan`s which have the habit of migrating around and making the results of calculations `nan`s. (This is by design.)

How does this work, then? The `np.isnan(a[:,1])` returns a boolean array with `True` at each position with a `nan` in column 1 in `a` and `False` for each valid number. As this is exactly the opposite of what we want, we'll negate it by adding the minus sign in front. And then the indexing picks only the rows which have numbers.

---

In case you have your X data and Y data in two different 1-D vectors, do this:

```
# original y data: Y
# original x data: X
# both have the same length

# calculate a mask to be used (a boolean vector)
msk = -np.isnan(Y)

# use the mask to plot both X and Y only at the points where Y is not NaN
plot(X[msk], Y[msk])
```

In some cases you may not have the X data at all, but you would like to number the points from, e.g. 0 onwards (as `matplotlib` does if you only give it one vector). There are a couple of possibilities, but this is one:

```
msk = -np.isnan(Y)
X = np.arange(len(Y))
plot(X[msk], Y[msk])
```

Comment: Ok, I've changed my list that has Nones to an array with nans.  Is the comma in the 'isnan' function necessary?  When I run it with the comma I get an error saying there are too many indices.  When I run it without, I get an empty array of length zero.

Comment: I got the 'isnan' method to work by removing the '[:,1]'.  The length of 'b' is now 287, but the graph's x-dimension is 1440.  Is there a way that I can reconcile the difference in dimensions?

Comment: @user3775711: See the edit for the case where you have 1-D vectors.